# Python - replace unique text

Tags: python, replace

I'm not sure how to go about replacing a string

If I have something like this `text1 = __test__ = "0"`

I want to be able to change `0` into anything I want.

I am trying to change a line inside a file

The caveat is that 0 can be anything.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn to use regex, what have you done so far in that regard?

Comment: Will the format always be "__test__ = $" ? You could just use split at '='

Comment: @RandomDavis yes, i will look into regex

Answer (score 2):

Use replace.

```
text1 = "__test__ = 0"
print(text1.replace('0','anything'))
```

Output

```
__test__ = anything
```

A comment reminded me that 0 can be anything, even a string so you can split the string at ' ' and take the last element then change it.

```
txt = text1.split(' ')
txt[-1] = 'anything'
print(' '.join(txt))
```

Comment: Read the question clearly. It need not be always 0. This is wrong answer

Comment: Based on recent edit, what is string is `"__test__ =  0 "`

Comment: Unless 0 is like another string, then I guess you could split at ' ' then take the last element

Comment: @AdityaSinghRathore it's a variable in a file, I would like to change what's after `=` operator

Answer (score 0):

I learned regex and this is my solution:

`text1 = re.sub(r'__test__.*', '__test__ = "1"', text1)`

this worked for me, thanks guys